# The set of numbers of the form $\frac{a}{10^b} \subset \Bbb R$, $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ is not isolated

Tags: real-analysis

If we want to show $\frac{a}{10^b}$, $a, b \in \Bbb Z$ is not isolated, then we have to show that $|\frac{a}{10^b} - \frac{c}{10^d}| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, since isolated means that there is a neighborhood that doesn't contain more than one point of the form $\frac{a}{10^b}$, so if it's not isolated then every neighborhood about the point $\frac{a}{10^b}$ must contain at least one other point of the form $\frac{a}{10^b}$. Or is there another alternative approach to this?

Comment: Actually this is a dense subgroup of $\Bbb{R}$, consisting of numbers whose decimal expansion terminates.

Comment: @Crostul So to prove this set is dense, I have to show that every neighborhood of a point of the form $\frac{a}{10^b}$ intersected with an open set of $\Bbb R$ is non-empty?

Comment: @morphic that's correct. But another way to show that it's dense would be to show that every real number $x$ can be expressed as the limit of a sequence of elements of the form $\frac a{10^b}$, and this is probably much easier.

Comment: Approach $\dfrac{a}{10^b}$ by $\dfrac{10^ca+1}{10^{b+c}}$ with $c$ large.